# Is there a GOOD way to use Angular.js and Indexed DB?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, indexeddb, offline-caching

So, I'm developing a javascript + api forum software. My point in this is so that you can read a forum while offline -- this involves HTML5's offline-storage. In particular, I would like to use IndexedDB as it seems to be the most promising for the future. I've gotten a good service/factory for fetching / temporarily storing the data, but IDDB is broken majorly. Does anybody have advice on how to go about this?

*edit* Also, for anybody who would like a hosted version, here it is on [cloud9](https://c9.io/tyler-elric/phoenix/workspace/index.html).

```
var angular = angular || {};
(function(w){
    w.localStorage = w.localStorage||{};
    w.indexedDB = w.indexedDB || w.mozIndexedDB || w.webkitIndexedDB || w.msIndexedDB || null;
    w.IDBTransaction = w.IDBTransaction || w.webkitIDBTransaction || w.msIDBTransaction || null;
    w.IDBKeyRange = w.IDBKeyRange || w.webkitIDBKeyRange || w.msIDBKeyRange || null;
})(this);

angular.module("JSForumServices",[],function($provide){
    $provide.factory('ForumStorage',(function(){
        var service = {
            post:null,
            thread:null,
            board:null,
            cache:{},
            pending:{}
        };
        var fetch = (function(baseFunction,path,callback){
            if(path in service.pending)
                return service.pending[path];
            var r=baseFunction();
            service.pending[path] = r;
            var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var cancelled = false;
            var dateRegex =
              /^(?:(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat),\s+)?(0[1-9]|[1-2]?[0-9]|3[01])\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(19[0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3})\s+(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?::(60|[0-5][0-9]))?\s+([-\+][0-9]{2}[0-5][0-9]|(?:UT|GMT|(?:E|C|M|P)(?:ST|DT)|[A-IK-Z]))(\s+|\(([^\(\)]+|\\\(|\\\))*\))*$/;
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = (function(){
                var readyState = ajaxRequest.readyState;
                if(readyState==4&&(!cancelled)){
                    // Store the copy locally!
                    // Also, initiate the callback.
                    // This way if the storage fails,
                    // The application continues to work
                    // As expected.
                    var data = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                    for(var k in data)
                        r[k] = data[k];
                    service.cache[path]={obj:r,modified:new Date()};
                    delete service.pending[path];
                    callback(r);
                }
                else if((path in service.cache)&&readyState>=2){
                    var oldDate = service.cache[path].modified;
                    console.log("Cache'd copy for",path,"exists.",oldDate.toString());
                    var isMoreRecent = false;//Is the server-copy more recent?
                    var serverModifiedString = ajaxRequest.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified");
                    console.log(serverModifiedString);
                    var match = dateRegex.exec(serverModifiedString);
                    var serverModified = new Date();
                    serverModified.setDate(parseInt(match[2],10));
                    serverModified.setMonth({
                        "jan":0,
                        "feb":1,
                        "mar":2,
                        "apr":3,
                        "may":4,
                        "jun":5,
                        "jul":6,
                        "aug":7,
                        "sep":8,
                        "oct":9,
                        "nov":10,
                        "dec":11
                    }[match[3].toLowerCase()]);
                    serverModified.setYear(parseInt(match[4],10));
                    serverModified.setHours(parseInt(match[5],10));
                    serverModified.setMinutes(parseInt(match[6],10));
                    serverModified.setMilliseconds(parseInt(match[7],10));
                    isMoreRecent = serverModified > oldDate;
                    if(!isMoreRecent&&(path in service.pending)){//sometimes this code may be slower than network speeds? Just to be safe, I guess.
                        cancelled=true;
                        var oldObject = service.cache[path].obj;
                        for(var key in oldObject)
                            r[key]=oldObject[key];
                        console.log("using a cache'd value.",r);
                        callback(r);
                        delete service.pending[path];
                        ajaxRequest.abort();//No need to waste more bandwidth!
                    }
                }
            });
            ajaxRequest.open("GET",path,true);
            ajaxRequest.send();
            return r;
        });
        var ObjectFetch = (function(base,constr){
            var ret = (function(id,cb){
                cb = cb||(function(){});
                return fetch(constr,base+id+".json",cb);
            });
            return ret;
        });
        service.post = ObjectFetch("./post/",(function(){
            return {
                id:"???",
                author:"???",
                content:"",
                date:""
            };
        }));
        service.thread = ObjectFetch("./thread/",(function(){
            return {
                id:"???",
                title:"???",
                posts:[],
                tags:""
            };
        }));
        service.board = ObjectFetch("./board/",(function(){
            return {
                id:"???",
                title:"???",
                threads:[],
                tags:""
            };
        }));
        service.forum = ObjectFetch("./",(function(){
            return {
                name:"Javascript Forum Software.",
                boards:[]
            };
        }));
        if(window.indexedDB!==null){
            var postFetch = service.post;
            var threadFetch = service.thread;
            var boardFetch = service.board;
            (function(dbengine){
                var boardsLoaded = false;
                var threadsLoaded = false;
                var postsLoaded = false;
                var req = dbengine.open("forum",1);
                req.onupgradeneeded = (function(e){
                   var db = e.target.result;
                   db.createObjectStore("post",{
                       keyPath:"id"
                   });
                   db.createObjectStore("thread",{
                       keyPath:"id"
                   });
                   db.createObjectStore("board",{
                       keyPath:"id"
                   });
                });
                req.onsuccess = (function(e){
                    service.database = e.target.result;
                    var loadData = service.database.transaction([
                        'board',
                        'thread',
                        'post'],'readwrite');
                    loadData.onsuccess = (function(ee){
                       var transaction = ee.target.result;
                       transaction.objectStore("board").openCursor().onsuccess=(function(e){
                           var cursor = e.target.result;
                           if(cursor===null){
                               boardsLoaded = true;
                               return;
                           }
                           var id = cursor.key;
                           var obj = cursor.value;
                           var lastModified = new Date();
                           if("lastModified" in obj){
                               lastModified = obj.lastModified;
                           }
                           service.cache["./board/"+id.toString().toLowerCase()+".json"]={
                               obj:obj,
                               modified:lastModified
                           };
                       });
                       transaction.objectStore("thread").openCursor().onsuccess=(function(e){
                           var cursor = e.target.result;
                           if(cursor===null){
                               threadsLoaded = true;
                               return;
                           }
                           var id = cursor.key;
                           var obj = cursor.value;
                           var lastModified = new Date();
                           if("lastModified" in obj){
                               lastModified = obj.lastModified;
                           }
                           service.cache["./thread/"+id.toString().toLowerCase()+".json"]={
                               obj:obj,
                               modified:lastModified
                           };
                       });
                       transaction.objectStore("post").openCursor().onsuccess=(function(e){
                           var cursor = e.target.result;
                           if(cursor===null){
                               postsLoaded = true;
                               return;
                           }
                           var id = cursor.key;
                           var obj = cursor.value;
                           var lastModified = new Date();
                           if("lastModified" in obj){
                               lastModified = obj.lastModified;
                           }
                           service.cache["./post/"+id.toString().toLowerCase()+".json"]={
                               obj:obj,
                               modified:lastModified
                           };
                       });
                       service.post = (function(id,cb){
                            console.log("DDDDDAFF");
                            var trans = service.database.transaction(["post"],"readwrite");
                            trans.onsuccess = (function(e){
                                var req = e.target.result.objectStore("post").get(id);
                                req.onsuccess = (function(ee){
                                    cb(req.result);
                                });
                                req.onerror = (function(ee){
                                    console.log("HAAAA?!");
                                    postFetch(id,(function(post){
                                        e.target.result.objcetStore.save(post);
                                        cb(post);
                                    }));
                                });
                            });
                            trans.onerror = (function(e){
                                console.log("Error with IDDB:",e);
                                threadFetch(id,cb);
                            });
                        });
                       service.thread = (function(id,cb){
                            var trans = service.database.transaction(["thread"],"readwrite");
                            trans.onsuccess = (function(e){
                                var req = e.target.result.objectStore("thread").get(id);
                                req.onsuccess = (function(ee){
                                    cb(req.result);
                                });
                                req.onerror = (function(ee){
                                    threadFetch(id,(function(post){
                                        e.target.result.objcetStore.save(post);
                                        cb(post);
                                    }));
                                });
                            });
                            trans.onerror = (function(e){
                                console.log("Error with IDDB:",e);
                                postFetch(id,cb);
                            });
                        });
                       service.board = (function(id,cb){
                            var trans = service.database.transaction(["board"],"readwrite");
                            trans.onsuccess = (function(e){
                                var req = e.target.result.objectStore("board").get(id);
                                req.onsuccess = (function(ee){
                                    cb(req.result);
                                });
                                req.onerror = (function(ee){
                                    boardFetch(id,(function(post){
                                        e.target.result.objcetStore.save(post);
                                        cb(post);
                                    }));
                                });
                            });
                            trans.onerror = (function(e){
                                console.log("Error with IDDB:",e);
                                boardFetch(id,cb);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            })(window.indexedDB);
        }
        return service;
    }));
});

angular.module('JSForum',["JSForumServices"]).config(
    ['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl:"forum.html",
        controller:ForumController
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/board/:id',{
        templateUrl:"board.html",
        controller:BoardController
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/thread/:id',{
        templateUrl:"thread.html",
        controller:ThreadController
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
}]);

function ThreadController($scope,$routeParams,ForumStorage){
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id.toString().toLowerCase();
    $scope.thread = null;
    ForumStorage.thread($scope.id,(function(thread){
        $scope.thread = thread;
        $scope.$apply();
        var callback = (function(p){
            return (function(post){
                $scope.thread.posts[p] = post;
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        });
        for(var i=0;i<thread.posts.length;i++)
            if(typeof(thread.posts[i].id) == 'undefined')
                ForumStorage.post(thread.posts[i],callback(i));
        $scope.$apply();
    }));
}

function BoardController($scope,$routeParams,ForumStorage){
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id.toString().toLowerCase();
    $scope.board = null;
    ForumStorage.board($scope.id,(function(board){
        var callback = (function(p){
            return (function(thread){
                $scope.board.threads[p] = thread;
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        });
        $scope.board = board;
        console.log("Using board:",$scope.board);
        for(var i=0;i<board.threads.length;i++)
            if(typeof(board.threads[i].id)=='undefined')
                ForumStorage.thread(board.threads[i],callback(i));
        $scope.$apply();
    }));
}

function ForumController($scope,ForumStorage){
    $scope.name = localStorage.forumName||"Forum";
    $scope.boards = [];
    ForumStorage.forum("forum",(function(forum){
        document.title = $scope.name = localStorage.forumName = forum.name;
        $scope.boards = forum.boards;
        var callback=(function(p){
            return (function(o){
                $scope.boards[p] = o;
                $scope.$apply();
            });
        });
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.boards.length;i++){
            if(typeof($scope.boards[i].id) == 'undefined')
                ForumStorage.board(forum.boards[i],callback(i));
        }
        $scope.$apply();
    }));
}
```

Comment: Can you stand up a working fiddle or elaborate on what you mean by `broken majorly`?  That's a lot of code to read through.

Comment: I mean it doesn't do anything yet, and when it did, its behavior wasn't consistent.

Anyways, [here](https://c9.io/tyler-elric/phoenix/workspace/index.html) is a Cloud9 running it.

Answer (score -1):

If your backend is google cloud storage, you can use my open source database library http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html It cached in IndexedDB and persist to blob store. forum post URI path is taken as primary key of the record. [LastModified](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#lastmodified) header value is persisted into IndexedDB and used for conditional HTTP request. since blob store can only be queried by ascending order of key (URI path), forum post URI path are generated so that the last post is the smallest. In this way, we can query new posts by giving smallest known key as [marker](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#marker).

An example can be found in https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-auth/src/master/examples/note-app/note-app.js (not forum, but a simple note app). you need a backend server that generate [signed url](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) for posting new record.

Comment: I like it! Is the IndexedDB caching easy enough to pull out and re-purpose, or is it fairly ingrained?

Comment: I am not sure your question. caching is optional.